Commutivity of two derivatives for exponential map
I'm reading the book Hörmander Operators by Marco Bramanti and Luca Brandolini World Scientific, 2023.
I had a problem when reading the proof of the following theorem:

Theorem 1.9 Let  $X$  and  $Y$  be smooth vector fields in a domain
$\Omega$  such that  $[X, Y] \equiv 0$ . Let  $x_{0} \in \Omega$ . There
exist  $\varepsilon>0$  such that for every  $|t|<\varepsilon $
\begin{array}{l} \exp (t X) \exp (t Y)\left(x_{0}\right)=\exp
 (t(X+Y))\left(x_{0}\right) ; \\ \exp (-t X) \exp (-t Y) \exp (t X)
\exp (t Y)\left(x_{0}\right)=x_{0} \end{array}
Proof. The second identity easily follows from the first one. To prove
the first identity, let  $\varphi(t)=\exp (t X) \exp (t
 Y)\left(x_{0}\right)$ . Clearly  $\varphi(0)=x_{0}$ . We will show that
$$\varphi^{\prime}(t)=X_{\varphi(t)}+Y_{\varphi(t)}\tag{1.8}$$
and therefore  $\varphi(t)=\exp (t(X+Y))\left(x_{0}\right) $. Let now
$$F(u, v)=\exp (u X) \exp (v Y)\left(x_{0}\right),$$
it follows that  $\varphi^{\prime}(t)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}(t,t)+\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}(t, t) $. For the first term we have
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}(t, t)=X_{\exp (t X) \exp (tY)\left(x_{0}\right)}=X_{\varphi(t)}$$
In order to evaluate  $\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}(t, t)$  we set
$G_{v}(u)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}(u, v)$ , we observe that
$G_{v}(0)=   Y_{\exp (v Y)\left(x_{0}\right)}$  and that
\begin{align} G_{v}^{\prime}(u) & =\frac{\partial^{2} F}{\partial v
\partial u}(u, v)=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(X_{\exp (u X) \exp
(v Y)\left(x_{0}\right)}\right) \\ & =J_{X}\left(\exp (u X) \exp (v
Y)\left(x_{0}\right)\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(\exp (u
X) \exp (v Y)\left(x_{0}\right)\right) \\ & =J_{X}\left(\exp (u X)
\exp (v Y)\left(x_{0}\right)\right) G_{v}(u) \end{align}
Let now  $H_{v}(u)=Y_{\exp (u X) \exp (v Y)\left(x_{0}\right)}$ ,
observe that  $H_{v}(0)=Y_{\exp (v Y)\left(x_{0}\right)}$  and that
\begin{aligned} H_{v}^{\prime}(u) & =J_{Y}\left(\exp (u X)\exp (v Y)
x_{0}\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(\exp (u X) \exp (v Y)
x_{0}\right) \\ & =J_{Y}\left(\exp (u X) \exp (v Y) x_{0}\right)
X_{\exp (u X) \exp (v Y) (x_{0})} 
\end{aligned}
Since the vector fields  $X$  and  $Y$  commute, by (1.7),  $J_{X}(x)Y_{x}=J_{Y}(x) X_{x}$  and therefore
\begin{aligned} H_{v}^{\prime}(u) & =J_{X}\left(\exp (u X) \exp (v Y)
x_{0}\right) Y_{\exp (u X) \exp (v Y) x_{0}} \\ & =J_{X}\left(\exp (u
 X) \exp (v Y) x_{0}\right) H_{v}(u) \end{aligned}
It follows that  $H_{v}$  and  $G_{v}$  satisfies the same Cauchy problem
so that
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}(u, v)=G_{v}(u)=H_{v}(u)=Y_{\exp (u X)
 \exp (v Y)\left(x_{0}\right)} .$$
Hence  $\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}(t, t)=Y_{\varphi(t)} $ and (1.8)
follows.

where (1.7) is
$$[X,Y]_x=J_Y(x)X_x-J_X(x)Y_x$$
$J_X$ is the Jacobian of the map $x\mapsto X_x$.
My main questions is at

\begin{align} G_{v}^{\prime}(u) & =\frac{\partial^{2} F}{\partial v
\partial u}(u, v)=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(X_{\exp (u X) \exp
(v Y)\left(x_{0}\right)}\right) \\ & =J_{X}\left(\exp (u X) \exp (v
Y)\left(x_{0}\right)\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(\exp (u
X) \exp (v Y)\left(x_{0}\right)\right) \\ & =J_{X}\left(\exp (u X)
\exp (v Y)\left(x_{0}\right)\right) G_{v}(u) \end{align}

There should be
$$G_{v}^{\prime}(u)=\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial u\partial v}(u,v),$$ why they can commute? It's not obviously for me, and there taking derivative for vector field and Jacobian make me confuse, it can be rewritten more strictly? Any anwser and comment are appreciate!
I have recognized this theorem can be corollary of Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula, but I wonder is it reasonable for the original proof.
Thanks for comment, it's necessary to give some definition. So $\Omega$ is a domain in some Lie group, and Lie bracket $[X,Y]$ as standard definition, where $exp(tX)(x_0)$ defined as a $C^1$ integral curve $\varphi(t)$, is the solution as Cauchy problem
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\varphi'(t)=X_{\varphi(t)}\\
\varphi(0)=x_0
\end{cases}
\end{align}

I suppose that $\Omega$ is a Lie group, and $\exp(tX)\exp(tY)$ refers to the group multiplication of $\exp(tX)$ and $\exp(tY)$? If this is the Riemannian exponential map, it's not clear what that term would mean..

According the book, it seens means composition, i.e. exp(tX)(exp(tY)(x_0)), this makes sense because exp(tY)(x_0) has became a point on Lie group, so...

The Lie exponential is defined as a map $\exp: \mathfrak{g} \to G$. How are you extending this to a map $\exp: \mathcal{X}(G) \to C^{\infty}(G)$? By $\exp(X)(x_0) := \exp(L_{x_0^{-1 \ast}}X_{x_0})$?

I'm sorry but I failed to following your extending...
